# Como hacer para que la pagina que se cargar por un menu salga justamente debajo del menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

me gustaria saber como puedo hacer que la pagina que cargue por un menu salga justamente abajo de este.
Les dejo una imagen para que vea como me sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden observar la pagina que se carga deberia aparecer justamente debajo del menu.

Este es el codigo del menu

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title>Bienvenido al control de tarjetas</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/menu1.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Capitan</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro.html" id = "addCap">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="contenido" name="contenido">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la hoja de estilo del menu

```css
* 
{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}   
#header 
{
 margin:auto;
 width:500px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}   
ul, ol 
{
 list-style:none;
}   
.nav 
{
 width:500px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
 
.nav > li
 {
 float:left;
}   
.nav li a 
{
 background-color:#000;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px 12px;
 display:block;
}   
.nav li a:hover 
{
 background-color:#434343;
}   
.nav li ul 
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 min-width:140px;
}   
.nav li:hover > ul 
{
 display:block;
}   
.nav li ul li 
{
 position:relative;
}   
.nav li ul li ul 
{
 right:-140px;
 top:0px;
}
```

y este css es el que le aplico a la pagina como tal

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 font: normal 18px/3 "Fira Sans", "Heveltica Neue", sans-serif;
 background: #3aafab;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
}

.form-registro{
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 background:white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 
}
h2{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}

.contenedor-input{
 padding: 10px 30px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.input-48{
 width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
 width: 100%;
}

select
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.btn-enviar{
 background: crimson;
 color: white;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-enviar:active{
 transform: scale(1.05);
}
.contenido{
 display:block
}
```

Gacias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola como estas?, puedes explicarte mejor que es lo que quieres cargar?, el código que pones es solo de un html con un menu.

Comment: Al hacer click a cualquier opcion del menu en este caso una solo que es la que tengo la pagina que carga es la que ves en la imgen, pero quiero que esta se carga justamente debajo del menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ese contenido es un frame?

Recuerda que si quienes mantener todo tu contenido web al centro puedes hacerlo encerrando todo en una clase llamada .contenedor así puedes reutilizarlo en el contenido que desees que centre y mantenga en caja.

Ejemplo:

```
   <div class="header>
      <div class="contenedor>  
        <nav>
            aqui va mi menu
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="main>
      <div class="contenedor>
        AQUI VA EL FORMULARIO O LA INFORMACION 
      </div>
    </div>

    <style>
     .contenedor {
       width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
     }
    </style>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda lo probaré y te comento como me fue

Comment: no me sirvio, sigue saliendo igual que en la imagen

Comment: Ya lo solucione, pero me toco agregar dos div de distintos nombres para que funcionara, gracias